# Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-home/user.device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

I have installed LVM on a free partition I had and did the following to create home directories on the Volume group:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
sudo vgcreate home /dev/sda3
sudo lvcreate -L 100G -n bwaters home
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L bwaters /dev/home/bwaters
sudo useradd bwaters
sudo passwd bwaters
sudo mkdir /home/bwaters
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

At this point, I add the below line to the bottom of the /etc/fstab file:

```
/dev/mapper/bwaters /home/bwaters ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Then I finished by mounting with

```
sudo mount -a
sudo cp -RT /etc/skel /home/bwaters
sudo chown -Rf bwaters:bwaters /home/bwaters
```

When I reboot, I get brought in to maintenance mode. Any errors you can see here?

Comment: Usually the volume group name features in the path under `/dev/mapper` ... I'd be curious to see the output of `sudo mount -a` above and the results under `df -m` ... :)

Comment: Can't have been that important ... :)

Comment: @tink I have resolved the issue. The partition I was using was an extended partition. Altered it to be Linux LVM partition and it worked fine.